Users that will be using a django form and posting data
I have created a django web app with CRUD functionality, i want to be able to see the users (With their names) that have posted on the form and see a full list of the data they post along with their names next to the data. I don't know how to go about coding that.
My Model code is:
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Agent(models.Model):

Role = [
    ('Manager','Manager'),
    ('Agent','Agent'),
]

QA_Agent = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, choices=Role)

def __str__(self):
    return self.QA_Agent.username

QA_Outcome = [
('FALSE','FALSE'),
('TRUE','TRUE'),
]

KPA_Outcome = [
   ('Product','Product'),
   ('Pass','Pass'),
   ('Compliance','Compliance'),
   ('Data Capturing','Data Capturing'),
   ('TCF','TCF'),
 ]

HIV_Test = [
    ('YES','YES'),
    ('NO','NO'),
]

AVS = [
    ('PASS', 'PASS'),
    ('FAIL', 'FAIL'),
    ('UNVERIFIED', 'UNVERIFIED'),

]

StartDate = [
    ('1st January','1st January'),
    ('1st February','1st February'),
    ('1st March','1st March'),
    ('1st April','1st April'),
    ('1st May','1st May'),
    ('1st June','1st June'),
    ('1st July','1st July'),
    ('1st August','1st August'),
    ('1st September','1st September'),
    ('1st October','1st October'),
    ('1st November','1st November'),
    ('1st December','1st December'),

]

# Create your models here.
class QA_Models(models.Model):
    Policy_Number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    Case_Number = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    AVS_Check = models.CharField(choices=AVS, max_length=12)
    Caller_ID = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Call_duration = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Start_date = models.CharField(choices=StartDate, max_length=20)
    Premium = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    Debit_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Cover_amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    QA_Correct = models.CharField(choices=QA_Outcome, max_length=5)
    KPA_1 = models.CharField(choices=KPA_Outcome, max_length=15, null=True)
    KPA_2 = models.CharField(choices=KPA_Outcome, max_length=15, null=True)
    KPA_3 = models.CharField(choices=KPA_Outcome, max_length=15, null=True)
    HIV_Required = models.CharField(choices=HIV_Test,  max_length=3)
    Comment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Case_Number

and post method in my view.py is
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . models import QA_Models, Agent
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . form import QA_Forms
from . decorations import allowed_user

# Create your views here.
@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Manager','Agent'])
def Home(request):
    TheData = QA_Models.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Home.html',
                  {'TheData':TheData})   

@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Manager','Agent'])
def MainPage(request):
    TheForm = QA_Forms
    TheUser = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        TheForm = QA_Forms(request.POST, request.user)
        if TheForm.is_valid():
            #TheForm.user = request.user
            TheForm.save()          
    return render(request, 'MainPage.html', {'TheForm':TheForm,
                                             'TheUser':TheUser})

My HTML is:
    {% extends "Layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Home </h1>
 <div class="container">
        <br>

        <table class="table table-dark table-hover">
            {% for Information in TheData %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{Information.Policy_Number}}<br>
                </td>
                <td>
                   <a href={% url 'DataInformation' Information.id  %}>
                      {{Information.Case_Number}}<br>
                   </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{Information.QA_Correct}}<br>
                </td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

        </table>
 </div>
{% endblock %}

Please let me show me how to go about using the user that posted on the form after they have logged in my web app.

It seems like what you're looking for would require a separate model to be created, which has a relationship back to your QA_Models. Feel free to remove the comments field from your original QA_Models model.
Let's see how this would potentially look like in practice by creating a Comment model.
Model example
class Comment(models.Model):
    qa_model = models.ForeignKey(
        QA_Models,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='comments',
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    content = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

This would then allow you too loop over all comments and their respective content and user, like so
Template example
    <h2>Comments</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for comment in Information.comments.all %}
        <li>{{ comment.content }} - {{ comment.user.username }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

I can't currently see your QA_Form, but imagine its briefly this CommentForm and you have something relatively similar to this, whereby
you're displaying a widget that has a comment_content attribute which we'll populate later in your view.
The fields list will be any other field which belongs to QA_Models that you want to validate against, if they're all sent over from the same page via a POST request.
Form example
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment_content = forms.CharField(label='Comment', widget=forms.Textarea)

    class Meta:
        model = QA_Models
        fields = ['Policy_Number',]

Your view will then proceed to save all other fields against the QA_Models and subsequently
create a comment object attached to it.
View example
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        qa_model = form.save()
        comment_content = form.cleaned_data['comment_content']
        qa_model.comments.create(content=comment_content, user=request.user)
        


Hi @David Silveiro, please tell me how would my views.py be if i were to continue.
